# exif image orientation is not working

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, exif

I have an application where users can upload an image by mobile.When I use the same image in my html document, It does not appear correctly. It appears automatically rotated. however, I tried image-orientation property it's working in moz but  not working in chrome.I used the below code

```css
.xyz{
    image-orientation:from-image
    }
```

```html
<img src="image/02020274842547347547357" class="xyz">
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation#BrowserCompatibility only FF does support it currently.

Comment: is there any way to do the same in google chrome

Comment: I think you'd have to read the [EXIF through js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js), then use CSS `transform : rotate()`...

Comment: Thanks, It helped

Answer (score 0):

As of Chrome 81 this is done automatically. Still unsupported in most other browsers.